# Programmatically add control to Grid RowDefition in WPF 4.5

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, .net-4.5

I've been through this site (and many others) trying to figure out what is going on and why this does not work. I am running VS2012 and have created a WPF C# app (target .NET 4.5). I am new to WPF, having spent many years coding Windows Forms apps, but decided to take the plunge, and am liking XAML so far.

Ultimately I want to:
1) Remove a user control in a particular Row (RowDefinition) in my Grid
2) Place another user control in  that particular Row

However I can't seem to place even a simple button control. What I want to do is place a button in Row 4 (3 with zero index). Here is my XAML:

```
<Window
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:Custom="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/ribbon"
x:Class="TestApp2_WindowsClient.MainWindow"
Title="Test App 2" Height="700" Width="1000" MinHeight="700" MinWidth="1000" MaxHeight="700" MaxWidth="1000" FontSize="12" FontFamily="Segoe UI Semibold">
<Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" Name="gridMain">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="152"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="240"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

<StackPanel Name="stackButtons1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" Margin="4,4,-310,4" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300" Orientation="Horizontal" >
        <Button Content="Show Bookings" Height="24" Margin="4,0,0,0" Click="Button_Click_1" />
        <Button Content="Show Radio Buttons" Height="24" Margin="4,0,0,0" Click="Button_Click_2" />
    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
</Window>
```

The button code (first button in Stack Panel) is:

```
Button MyControl = new Button();
MyControl.Content = "Test Button!";

Grid.SetRow(MyControl, 3); 
Grid.SetColumn(MyControl, 0); 
gridMain.Children.Add(MyControl);
```

I can see (in my watch) that the gridMain.Children count value increases every time I click the first button, but nothing appears on the screen.

It's probably something really silly, but a few hours of searching and trying a stack of different code has not helped.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: While nothing to do with the answer to the question, this question _did_ solve the issue I was stuck on (I was looking for Grid.SetRow, Grid.SetColumn, and <gridName>.Children.Add).  Thanks for that!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
<ColumnDefinition Width="0"/>
```

Maybe you could see the button if you increased the width.

Comment: Worth noting that these issues can often be diagnosed by using Snoop